# Add one to a binary representation with padding of 0

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a character representation of a binary number, and I wish to perform arithmetic, plus 1, on it. I want to keep the padding of 0.

Right now I have :

```
int value = fromBinary(binaryCharArray);
value++;

int fromBinary(char *s) {
    return (int)strtol(s, NULL, 2);
}
```

I need to transform the value++ to binary representation and if I have 0 to pad I need to pad it.

0110 -> 6

6++ -> 7

7   -> 0111 <- that's what I should get from transforming it back in a character representation

In my problem it will never go above 15.

This is what I have so far

```
char *toBinary(int value) 
{ 
    char *binaryRep = malloc(4 * sizeof(char)); 
    itoa(value, binaryRep, 2); 
    if (strlen(binaryRep) < 4) 
    { 
        int index = 0; 
        while (binaryRep[index] != '1') 
        { 
            binaryRep[index] = '0'; 
            index++;
        }
    }
    return binaryRep; 
}
```

Comment: How are you *transforming* it back?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I tried `itoa`, in base 2, but it doesn't give me leading zeros

Comment: `itoa()` is not a standard function, it's very easy to write such a function. What have you tried?

Comment: `char* toBinary(int value) {
 char* binaryRep = (char *)malloc(4* sizeof(char));
 itoa(value, binaryRep, 2);
 if (strlen(binaryRep) < 4) {
  int index = 0;
  while (binaryRep[index] != '1') {
   binaryRep[index] = '0';
   index++;
  }
 }
 return binaryRep;
}`

That doesn't work because the size is already 4, it will never iterate

Comment: It looks like a very bad implementation, do you know about bitwise operators?

Comment: I probably need to use right or left bit shift.

Comment: And you also need to learn about [tag:c] [tag:strings], because yours is not one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93634/discussion-between-maxime-roussin-belanger-and-iharob).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x;
    char binary[5]; /* You need 5 bytes for a 4 character string */

    x = 6;
    for (size_t n = 0 ; n < 4 ; ++n)
    {
        /* shift right `n' bits and check that the bit is set */
        binary[3 - n] = (((x >> n) & 1) == 1) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    /* nul terminate `binary' so it's a valid c string */
    binary[4] = '\0';

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", binary);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *binaryRep = malloc(4* sizeof(char));
binaryRep[4] = '\0';
for (int i = (sizeof(int)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    binaryRep[i] = (value & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
}
return binaryRep;
```

This does what I need.

Comment: Do not post this as an answer, an answer was already posted. It worked and I am glad. But this is not how SO works, if the answer I posted helped you can accept it, or accept any answer you think helped.

Comment: I was done before you posted your answer, I used the comment about bitwise operation to create my solution

Comment: ALright then, it's ok. You can accept your own answer too.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
/*___________________________________________________________
*/

int from_bin(char *buff){
    int d=0;
    while(*buff){
        d<<=1;
        d+=(*buff=='1')?1:0;
        buff++;
    }
    return d;
}
/*___________________________________________________________
*/


int to_bin(int d,char *buff,int len){
    int ret=0;
    if(len<4)return -1;
    if(d & ~0xf){

        ret=to_bin(d>>4,buff,len-4);
        if(ret==-1) return -1;
        buff+=ret;
    }

    buff[4]=0;

    buff[3]=((d & 0x1)?'1':'0');
    d>>=1;

    buff[2]=((d & 0x1)?'1':'0');
    d>>=1;

    buff[1]=((d & 0x1)?'1':'0');
    d>>=1;

    buff[0]=((d & 0x1)?'1':'0');
    d>>=1;

    return ret+4;
}
/*___________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void){
    int n;
    char buff[33]="0011";

    n=from_bin(buff);

    n+=1;

    if(to_bin(n,buff,8)==-1){
        printf("ERROR: buffer too small\n");
    }else{
        printf("bin of %d= '%s'\n",n,buff);
    }

    return 0;

}
```